# Angular v1.4.9 $badreq error, failing before interceptor can add url

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

In patch v1.4.9 Angular added a `$badreq` error when a `$http` call has no `url` param, but in my code if no url is set it is added in my `interceptor` and pointed at my `api`.

Since it now fails before reaching the `interceptor` my application is completely broken.

Is there a way to either skip the check or get into the `interceptor` before the check ?

---

From the patch notes:

**$http:** throw if url passed is not a string
([c5bf9dae](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c5bf9daef6dfdb3e4a2942c21155a9f67d92e237),
[#12925](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12925), [#13444](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13444))

Answer (score 0):

The commit in your question shows they use `angular.isString`, which simply checks if the type equals to `string`, you might be able to just pass the empty string and catch that in your interceptor. Does that work for your scenario?

If all else fails, and it's absolutely necessary, you can always just change your AngularJS copy or comment on the issues on Github. It is open source after all!